# Why does join use rows that were sent after watermark of 20 seconds?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I’m using watermark to join two streams as you can see below:

```
val order_wm = order_details.withWatermark("tstamp_trans", "20 seconds")
val invoice_wm = invoice_details.withWatermark("tstamp_trans", "20 seconds")
val join_df = order_wm
  .join(invoice_wm, order_wm.col("s_order_id") === invoice_wm.col("order_id"))
```

My understanding with the above code, it will keep each of the stream for 20 secs. After it comes but, when I’m giving one stream now and the another after 20secs then also both are getting joined. It seems like even after watermark got finished Spark is holding the data in memory. I even tried after 45 seconds and that was getting joined too.

This is creating confusion in my mind regarding watermark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the doc from: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#inner-joins-with-optional-watermarking

In other words, you will have to do the following additional steps in the join.

Define watermark delays on both inputs such that the engine knows how delayed the input can be (similar to streaming aggregations)

Define a constraint on event-time across the two inputs such that the engine can figure out when old rows of one input is not going to be required (i.e. will not satisfy the time constraint) for matches with the other input. This constraint can be defined in one of the two ways.

Time range join conditions (e.g. ...JOIN ON leftTime BETWEEN rightTime AND rightTime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR),

Join on event-time windows (e.g. ...JOIN ON leftTimeWindow = rightTimeWindow).

Answer (score 0):

> After it comes but, when I’m giving one stream now and the another after 20secs then also both are getting joined.

That's possible since the time measured is not the time of events as they arrive, but the time that is inside the watermarked field, i.e. `tstamp_trans`. You have to make sure that the last time in `tstamp_trans` is 20 seconds after the rows that will participate in the join.

Comment: I'm adding tstamp_trans as a column using .withcolumn in which I'm providing current timestamp

Comment: Can you include how you tested the application and what output you got?

Comment: I'm getting two streams from kafka. I opened two kafka producer and then I'm sending those two streams. I'm sending data in one kafka topic and waiting for watermark time to finish and then pushing the other